# Unit testing involving hardware communication worth it?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, embedded

I am developing a C# application that involves communication with hardware devices such as an NFC reader and Spectrometer. We have the hardware already and I am not sure if it is still worth the time converting the hardware into mock classes. I am thinking of testing the software functions together with the hardware device.

Is there still any benefit conducting unit tests without hardware? Currently i do not have the interfaces for the different hardware classes. It would seem to require some work to properly configure the hardware interface classes.

I am using DLLImports for the hardware communication. I’m not sure if im able to simulate these dll calls using a fake class as well ?

Comment: Whilst it´s not really what we consider a **unit**-test it may be worth the afford of being tested within an **integration**-test however. But if that´s really the case is completely up to your personal preferences and your environment.

Comment: Typically you'd mock the hardware results for unit testing, which shouldn't be testing anything outside your own code.  As others have said, you're talking about integration testing.

Comment: yup. I was thinking of skipping unit testing and just go for integration testing ?

Answer (score 2):

Testing communication with the actual hardware device would become a *Integration Testing* but you are more inclined towards performing an *Unit Test*. I would say you just test the unit (method) that does communicate with the H/W piece and assert accordingly.